# How can i import export with foreign key relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have csv file with user addresses, and his phone number, How can i import it in my address table. Since I dont know user id of each user.

**CSV FILE in xlsx:** [image: xlsx file]
**Format of csv:**

```
user_id__phone,address1,address2,state,country,pincode

99999999,"addrss","addres2",somestate,Country,11111
```

i'm getting following error

```
Line number: 1 - null value in column "user_id_id" of relation "proj_auth_useraddress" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains (432, null, null, someaddress, , , null).
```

But i know relationship of user and address is through his phone number. `user_id__phone`

```
# Models.py
class AppUser(AbstractUser):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True, null=True)
    ...
class UserAddress(models.Model):
    address_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(AppUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lat = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    lng = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pincode = models.IntegerField()

# Admin.py
@admin.register(UserAddress)
class AddressAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = AddressAdminResource

# Resource.py
class AddressAdminResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = UserAddress
        import_id_fields = ('address_id',)
```

Comment: Share the csv file structure so that we can help better

Comment: where is the code to import data (View)

Comment: @PavanKumarTS its in `# Admin.py` and `# Resource.py`   Im using `ImportExportModelAdmin`  for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **phone** in **AppUser** is unique for each user then you can use **pandas** to migrate records from csv to database

You can try below solutions:

```
import pandas as pd

csv_file = pd.read_csv(<yourcsvfile>.csv)

for index, rows in csv_file.iterrows():
    user_id__phone = rows["user_id__phone"]
    address1 = rows["address1"]
    address2 = rows["address2"]
    country = rows["country"]
    pincode = rows["pincode"]
    
    appuser_instance = AppUser.objects.get(phone=user_id__phone)
    
    # get_or_create is used to eliminate forming or any duplicate record 
    usershipping, created = UserAddress.objects.get_or_create(
        user_id=appuser_instance,
        address1=address1,
        address2=address2,
        city=city,
        pincode=pincode
        )
    
    # created defines whether new record was created or was edited on existing record
    # created = True (new record created)
    # craeted = False (edited on existing record)
    
    if created:
        usershipping.save()
```

Comment: This solution helped me in many of my project when it involved migration of data from csv to Django database

Comment: Thanks man.. I know it works but i figure out with doing some query for userid